# detailTextLabel text not displaying for cell with UITableViewCellStyleValue1

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I want to show the detail label text on the right side of the cell but I have had no success.

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{ 
    static NSString *CellIdentifier =@"Cell";
    UITableViewCell* cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    cell.textLabel.text = [(AGSGraphic *)[_radios objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] attributeForKey:@"radio];

    NSNumber *timestamp = [[_radios objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] attributeForKey:@"date"];
    NSDate *newDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:[timestamp doubleValue] / 1000];
    NSString *date =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", newDate];

    NSDateFormatter *f = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [f setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
    NSDate *startDate = [NSDate date];
    NSDate *endDate = [f dateFromString:date];
    NSCalendar *gregorianCalendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
    NSDateComponents *components = [gregorianCalendar
                                    components:NSMinuteCalendarUnit
                                    fromDate:endDate
                                    toDate:startDate
                                    options:0];
    NSDateComponents *components2 = [gregorianCalendar components:NSHourCalendarUnit fromDate:endDate toDate:startDate options:0];
    //NSDateComponents *components3 = [gregorianCalendar components:NSDayCalendarUnit fromDate:endDate toDate:startDate options:0];
    NSInteger mins = [components minute];
    NSInteger hours = [components2 hour];
    //NSInteger days = [components3 day];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"test";
    cell.detailTextLabel.frame.origin.y, 44.0, 44.0);
    return cell;
}
```

When I use:

```
initwithstyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle
```

It works but I don't want the detail label under the title, I want it to the right of the title. I tried changing the style to `UITableViewCellStyleValue1` and it does nothing.

Comment: what are you doing with frame...?

Comment: Subclass UITableViewCell, override initWithStyle and return UITableViewCellStyleValue1... then proceed as usual

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use

```
UITableViewCell* cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
```

Your cell will be already initialized, dequeue takes the configuration of your storyboards (this is why changing the style from the init isn't working for you), to change it use the storyboards right tools and select `Left Detail` or `Right Detail` under Table View Cell's Style depending on how do you want to show your data

[image]

And delete this line:

```
cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
```

And this:

```
cell.detailTextLabel.frame.origin.y, 44.0, 44.0);
```

Comment: ok this worked but now both the title and detail are in the middle of the cell, how do you align them?

Comment: What do you mean with align them?, you can use `Right Detail` if you want that the title appears on the left most of the cell, and the detail on the right most of the cell.

Comment: right detail just shows what is in the title when i use it.

Comment: remove `cell.detailTextLabel.frame.origin.y, 44.0, 44.0);`

Comment: it was the pod file i am using it was hiding the text behind my map view. I am using a split view controller

Comment: I'm glad i've helped you

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried checking `cell` before the `init`, e.g.

```
UITableViewCell* cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the table view in your storyboard, set the cell to `Right Detail` and set the reuse identifier to something. Then the beginning part of your cellForRow will look like this:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{ 
    UITableViewCell* cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"TheReuseIdentifierYouSet"];
    // No more need to alloc/init a table view cell
    // ...
```

If you are not using a storyboard, then create a new `UITableViewCell` subclass and .xib. Drag a `UITableViewCell` out, set it to right detail and set the reuse identifier. Then you can register this class with the table view in `viewDidLoad` using `registerNib:forCellReuseIdentifier:` or `registerClass:forCellReuseIdentifier:`.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
    }
    cell.textLabel.text = @"Left Text";
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"Right Text";
    // Configure the cell...

    return cell;
}
```